# Difference between arrange and make arrangements

Tags: verbs

Can anyone tell me the difference between arrange to/for and make arrangements to? Here is the sentence: During the discussion, we’ll make arrangements to send your $50 Amazon gift card! OR During the discussion, we'll arrange to send your $50 Amazon gift card!

Comment: Either works here, but they're not always interchangeable. 'Make arrangements' emphasises the process more; 'arrange' is less marked in this respect.

Comment: I think "make arrangements" pushes the arranging farther away -- perhaps a third party does the sending.